# Protect thumbnail and library images from media browser from being deleted in Drupal 7

Tags: image, drupal, media, media-library

I have a Drupal 7 site where authenticated users can create a webpage to raise money for a charity. They can add a picture from the media library using the media browser. However, if they delete their page, this deletes the thumbnail and the library image from the db and site. I've tried the File Lock module, but that doesn't work. I've set the user permissions to where the images cannot be deleted; that doesn't work. The images are used in other places as well as the need to keep them library for future users. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running on a linux box, you can make those files read-only using a crontab.

As a superuser, type

crontab -e

Add this line to your crontab

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/mysite/sites/default/files/yourcustomimagesfoldername/ && find . -type f -exec chmod 444 {} +
```

To explain, this line changes directory to your images folder, then makes every single file in the images folder read-only, then iterates through all subdirectories as well. You may need to tweak chmod slightly based on your distro.

It does not alter your directory permissions.

Best,